# Continuity of a function - Please explain what this answer means and how it is true

Tags: calculus

$$
f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2\sin (\frac{1}{x}) & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0. \end{cases}
$$

$\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous for all $x \neq 0$ and since both $\sin(x)$ and $x^2$ are continuous functions, it follows that $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is continuous for all $x \neq 0$. Thus, $f$ is continuous for all $x$ which are an element of $\mathbb {R}$.

The part I don't understand of this explanation is how can $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ can be continuous for all $x \neq 0$ but then it claims that therefore $f$ is continuous for all $x$ which are elements of $\mathbb {R}$. This seems contradictory?

Please give an elaborate explanation of why this is true and not contradictory. Thank you.

Comment: YOu should **really** lears MathJax and write in areadable manner your posts.  After 46 days being a member and 17 questions asked I'd say it is about time. Also, that "Thus" in your third line is uncalled for.

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm just copying out what the answer said. Those aren't my words. And I'm working on the MathJax.

Comment: Then copy them with MathJaX... *and explain*. Some of us can't still read minds.

Comment: I meant I'm working on learning it.

Comment: @DonAntonio Perhaps that is better?

Comment: For example $!=$ should be replaced by \neq (Not EQual) which gives you $\neq$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If** the function is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\frac1x,&x\neq0\\{}\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$$

then this function is clearly continuous for $\;x\neq0\;$ as the product of two continuous functions and. in fact, it is also continuous at zero since

$$\lim_{x\to0}x^2\sin\frac1x=0$$

Even more, the function is *differentiable* at zero, as you can check by the definition.

Comment: My question is asking what this answer I was given means: 1/x is continuous for all x != 0 and since both sin(x) and x^2 are continuous functions, it follows that x^2sin(1/x) is continuous for all x != 0. Thus, f is continuous for all x which are an element of R.

Comment: The above answer was given to me by someone else but it doesn't make sense to me. In fact, it seems contradictory. I would like someone to clarify it.

Comment: The answer you give (that someone else gave you) is lacking. I completed it.

Comment: I thought so. Ok, thanks then. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not contradictory but it is incomplete.

$f = x^2\sin \frac 1x$ at all points where $x \ne 0$ so $f$ is continuous at all points $x \ne 0$.

At $x = 0$, $f$ is not $x^2\sin \frac 1x$ but $f(0) = 0$.

Now the statement *utterly* neglects to state and to prove that $f$ is continuous and $x = 0$.

**IF** the statement had been claimed *then* we could have concluded $f$ is continuous on all reals.  But without knowing $f$ is continuous at $0$ we can not make such a claim.

Such a claim *isn't* contradictory as $f$ is not the same thing as $x^2 \sin \frac 1x$.  But we can't make it...

.... unless we prove $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Which is simply a matter of showing $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^2 \sin \frac 1x = f(0) = 0$.

Let's do it.

$0 \le |\sin 1/x| \le 1$.  So $0 \le|x^2\sin \frac 1x| \le |x^2|$.  So for any $\epsilon > 0$ if $|x - 0|< \sqrt{\epsilon}$ then $|x^2\sin \frac 1x - 0| < |x^2| = |x|^2 < \sqrt{\epsilon}^2 = \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^2 \sin \frac 1x = 0$.    So $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$.

.... and $f$ is continuous at $x \ne 0$.  So $f$ is continuous at all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the function sin(1/x) is undefined at x=0. However for continuity u need to have the right and left hand limit and functional value equal. Which in this case is indeed true